# java 8 - iterate 2 hash maps and create new hash map with records only matching keys

Tags: hashmap, iteration

we have a requirement to achieve in java8, please anyone help us.

we have method taking 2 parameters as input, both parameters are Hashmap<String,Dog>.

we want to iterate both hash maps and return one hashmap .

result hash Map contains only matched keys and corresponding values from 2 hashmaps, and (value for matched key) i.e Dog atributes we want to set some attribute from Hashmap1 and some attributes from hashmap2.

please suggest how we can achieve this in java 8.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the iterator simple like this:

```
    public Map<String, Dog> combineMap(Map<String, Dog> first, Map<String, Dog> second) {
        Map<String, Dog> result = new HashMap<>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Dog> entry : first.entrySet()) {
            if(second.containsKey(entry.getKey())){
                Dog dogFirst = entry.getValue();
                Dog dogSecond = second.get(entry.getKey());
                Dog combineDog = new Dog();
                // Do what ever you want with combineDog 
                result.put(entry.getKey(), combineDog);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Hi , Thank you very much for suggesting, we would like to have this logic to be implemented in java8 through any functional interfaces like consumer , bi function. could you help

Comment: Yeah, you can use forEach method like this:
`
first.forEach((keyFirst, valueFirst) -> {
            
});
`